# Links with target="_blank" jquery-mobile require two clicks when viewed in safari view controller

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, user-agent, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have a jquery mobile web app that has links that look like this:

```
<a href="EXTERNAL_URL" class="ui-btn" rel="external" target="_blank">LINK TEXT</a>
```

When users come to my site using Safari View Controller (that is, they're on an iphone or ipad but they're inside an app like Apple's News app, not running Safari on its own.) this link doesn't work at first. On the first click, nothing happens. On the second click it goes to its intended location.

How can I fix this? I want to do something like this:

```
if (((strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPhone')) ||
(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad')))
&&
(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Safari'))){
    //
}else{
    $blank='target="blank"';
}
```

and then just put $blank into the link:

```
<a href="EXTERNAL_URL" class="ui-btn" rel="external" <?=$blank?>>LINK TEXT</a>
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?